# Android Hijacks CSS of Input Field During Focus?

Tags: android, css, input, focus

I have a nicely formatted text input field on my web app, but Android hijacks my CSS as soon as the user brings the field into focus. It looks ugly -- the borders lose their radius, the font and font size changes, the background gets changed, etc. How do I get rid of this?

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [flowtab.mobi](http://flowtab.mobi/wp-content/uploads/images/seriously.png))</sub>

I was able to get rid of the border color using the CSS below, but adding anything else (font style, font color, etc.) doesn't seem to override the default formatting given by the browser:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a known bug in ICS:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30964

Alternative is to use it as plain text:

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

But has plenty of side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to test this, but you could try using `!important` on your various rules.  The `!important` keyword is useful in forcing your page's behavior to conform to your own CSS.

Comment: I see the same behavior. At least for me, the !important flag has no effect.